# Maintaining Units of measure across type converstions

Tags: f#, units-of-measurement

If we define a unit of measure like:

```
[<Measure>] type s
```

and then an integer with a measure

```
let t = 1<s>
```

and then convert it to a float

```
let r = float t
```

we see that `r = 1.0` without a measure type.  This seems very odd, as all the measure information has been lost.

You can use `LanguagePrimitives.FloatWithMeasure` to convert back to a float with something like

```
let inline floatMeasure (arg:int<'t>) : (float<'t>) =
    LanguagePrimitives.FloatWithMeasure (float arg)
```

which enforces the right types, but this doesn't feel like the right solution as the docs for units of measure (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233243.aspx) say

> However, for writing interoperability layers, there are also some explicit functions that you can use to convert unitless values to values with units. These are in the Microsoft.FSharp.Core.LanguagePrimitives module. For example, to convert from a unitless float to a float, use FloatWithMeasure, as shown in the following code.

Which seems to suggest that the function should be avoided in F# code.

Is there a more idiomatic way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Caveat: I've not used units much in anger.)

I think that the only negative for using e.g. `FloatWithMeasure` is the unit-casting aspect (unitless to unitful).  I think this is conceptually orthogonal to the numeric-representation-casting aspect (e.g. `int` to `float`).  However there is (I think) no library function to do numeric-representation-casting on unit-ful values.  Perhaps this is reflective of the fact that most unitful values model real-world continuous values, as so discrete representations like `int` are typically not used for them (e.g. `1<s>` feels wrong; surely you mean `1.0<s>`).

So I think it's fine to 'cast representations' and then 'readjust units', but I wonder how you got the values with different representations in the first place, as it's often typical for those representations to be fixed for a domain (e.g. use `float` everywhere).

(In any case, I do like your `floatMeasure` function, which un-confounds the unit-aspect from the representation-aspect, so that if you do need to only change representation, you have a way to express it directly.)

Comment: I see your point here.  I thought I would add that this cropped up as I was stepping forward a simularion in discrete time steps (for which `int` is nice) but using the total time in some of my equations.  Probably the real answer is to avoid using `int` at all.

Answer (score 2):

Here's working snippet that does exactly what you need although gives warning

> stdin(9,48): warning FS0042: This construct is deprecated: it is only for use in the F# library)):

```
[<NoDynamicInvocation>]
let inline convert (t: int<'u>) : float<'u> = (# "" t : 'U #)

[<Measure>] type s
let t = 1<s>
let t1 = convert t // t1: float<s>
```

However, I wouldn't suggest this approach.
First of all, UoM are compile-time, while type conversion `let r = float t` is runtime. At the moment of invocation, `int -> float` has no idea of whether it is `int<s>` or `int<something_else>`. So it is simply unable to infer a proper `float<'u>` *at runtime*.

Another thought is that philosophy behind UoM is wider than it's described. It is like saying the compiler, "well, it is `int`, but please treat it as `int<s>`". The goal is avoiding occasional improper use (e.g., adding `int<s>` to `int<hours>`).
Sometimes it makes no sense of `int -> float` conversion: think of `int<ticks>`, there is no sense of `float<ticks>`.

[Further reading](http://blog.moertel.com/articles/2006/10/18/a-type-based-solution-to-the-strings-problem), credits to @kvb for pointing on this article.

Comment: `let t1 : float<s> = unbox float t` also works, but it is not generic.